# Case class serialazation in flink

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-flink

I am trying to build a dataset using a case class for Scala (I would like to use case classes over tuples because I want to join fields by name).

Here is one iteration of a join I am working on:

```
case class TestTarget(tacticId: String, partnerId:Long)

campaignPartners.join(partnerInput).where(1).equalTo("id") {
   (target, partnerInfo, out: Collector[TestTarget]) => {
       partnerInfo.partner_pricing match {
           case Some(pricing) =>
             out.collect(TestTarget(target._1, partnerInfo.partner_id))
           case None => ()
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously this throws the error:

> org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Task not
>   serializable  at
>   org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:171)
>     at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.clean(DataSet.scala:121)  at
>   org.apache.flink.api.scala.JoinDataSet$$anon$2.(joinDataSet.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.api.scala.JoinDataSet.apply(joinDataSet.scala:107)
>     at
>   com.adfin.dataimport.vendors.dbm.Job.calculateVendorFees(Job.scala:84)

I have seen the docs [here](https://flink.apache.org/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-a-nonserializableexception-) that state that I need to implement serializable for the class. As far as I can tell in new versions of Scala there is no good way to automatically serialize case classes. (I looked into manual serialization but I think I would need to do some extra work with link for this to work).

Edit: 
As per  Till Rohrmann's suggestion I tried to reproduce this error using a small case. This is what I used to try and reproduce the error. This example worked and I failed to reproduce the error. I also tried putting Option cases everywhere but that cause the job to fail either.

```
val text = env.fromElements("To be, or not to be,--that is the question:--")

val words = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }.map(x => (1,x))

val nums = env.fromElements(List(1,2,3,4,5)).flatMap(x => x).map(x => First(1,x))



val counts = words.join(nums).where(0).equalTo("a") {
  (a, b, out: Collector[TestTarget]) => {
    b.b match {
      case 2 => ()
      case _ => out.collect(TestTarget(a._2, b.b))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example which reproduces your problem?

Comment: What else do you need? After I call this function I output it using writeAsText. campaignPartners and PartnerInfo are DataSets do you want the type signatures for them?

Comment: I tested your example with Flink `1.1-SNAPSHOT` and it worked perfectly fine. If the error should still remain for you, could you please post a complete example including types `First` and where you defined them (one which one can simply copy & paste). Ideally you simply post the Scala file.

Comment: Sorry the small example worked as in I couldn't reproduce the error

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread that. What about your initial program?

Comment: Ill see what I can do. The original program is actually rather large since it involves a bunch of transformations and custom importers. edit: I am using scala 1.0.0

Comment: I figured it out. Do you think I should update my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of my program used a class

```
class Job(conf: AdfinConfig)(implicit env: ExecutionEnvironment)
        extends DspJob(conf){
    ...
    case class TestTarget(tacticId: String, partnerId:Long)
    campaignPartners.join(partnerInput).where(1).equalTo("id") {
    ...
}
```

Since it was an inner class it wasn't being serialized automatically

If you switch the class to not be an inner class then everything works out

```
case class TestTarget(tacticId: String, partnerId:Long)
class Job(conf: AdfinConfig)(implicit env: ExecutionEnvironment)
        extends DspJob(conf){
    ...
    words.join( ....) 
    ...
}
```

Comment: This issue can come up with Kryo / RocksDB serialization as well.  When I tried to serialize a inner `case class` to RocksDB via Kryo, I got the following error:

`com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to org.joda.time.DateTime`

For some reason Kryo interprets case classes as Tuple2 objects, and makes the error non-sensical.

Problem was fixed by moving all my inner case classes to be non-inner case classes.